# Using Handbrake CLI .to get dvd tv episodes

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, dvd-burning, handbrake

What does the `0 2>&1 >/dev/null` below mean?

```
rawout=$(HandBrakeCLI -i /dev/dvd -t 0 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

also below,

```
count=$(echo $rawout | grep -Eao "\\+ title [0-9]+:" | wc -l)
```

what does the `-Eao "\\+ title [0-9]+:" | wc -l)` imply?

Answer (score 2):

According to [HandBreak cli documentation](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/command-line-reference.html):

The `-t 0` option means "scan all titles only".

Additionally, `2>&1 >/dev/null` is a linux terminal output redirection of your errors (error stream) to your outpus stream (which displays general command and output messages to the terminal), and both of them redirected to `/dev/null` special device file wich discards whatever is sent to it.

 **It is a method of making a command silent and not show you any messages.**

The expression `grep -Eao "\\+ title [0-9]+:" | wc -l` is a combination of the output of `grep -Eao "\\+ title [0-9]+:"` sent to the `wc -l` command, which counts the number of lines in a file or a command output.

In other words: count how many lines the command `grep -Eao "\\+ title [0-9]+:"` outputs.

 **More about** `wc` **in the** [wc manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc).

The `grep` util performs a search of a given expression pattern inside a file or a command output:

 The `-a` option means "handle this data given as text data".

 The option `-E` is a deprecated option of `grep` which sometimes used to treat patterns as extended regex.

 lastly, `-o` means "show only matching results of a whole matching line".

Overall the use of `grep` here seems to be a searching mechanism for an series title and episode, and display their name.

 **More about** `grep` **in the** [grep manpage](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html).

Comment: Thank You Pizza. Much appreciated.

Comment: However, I think "2>&1 >/dev/null" is redirecting the errors to the terminal and the output to the null!! At least that what I understood when I did a bit of research. What puzzles me is WHY?  

rawout=$(HandBrakeCLI -i /dev/dvd -t 0 2>&1 >/dev/null) ;
count=$(echo $rawout | grep -Eao "\\+ title [0-9]+:" | wc -l);  

This script is trying to enumerate the number of episodes in a disc. FYI

Comment: @Babek Yes, regarding `/dev/null` that's exactly what I wrote. As I also mentioned, it is a common way of silencing a program so it won't interfere any built in outputs or confuse the user when an OS command error occurs, while the author usually handles it themselves within the script.

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted (The V button) so it won't appear as "Unanswered", and you are more than welcome to upvote it if it was clear enough to understand.

Comment: Thanks. How do I mark it as accepted???  sorry no idea

Comment: Ok I think I have done it, not terribly sure though. Apologies